# I want to customise my own version of node.js for cloudbees

Tags: node.js, cloudbees

I want to use a specific version of node.js which is not listed as available - how can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clone Cloudbees’ nodejs clickstack and edit config:

```
git clone https://github.com/CloudBees-community/nodejs-clickstack.git 
cd nodejs-clickstack 
edit Makefile
```

change Makefile to use node version 0.8.24 - for example (or anything else you need) - make any other changes.

Build the clickstack package and publish out to Amazon S3:

```
make publish
```

This spits out a URL where the package has been uploaded; 
https://s3.amazonaws.com/clickstacks/youraccount/nodejs-plugin-0.8.24.zip

Update the configuration for the Cloudbees runtime and then restart.

```
bees config:set –R PLUGIN.SRC.nodejs=https://s3.amazonaws.com/clickstacks/atsid/nodejs-plugin-0.8.24.zip -a atsid/talentpool 
bees app:restart
```